# Python Error Shows Innaccurate Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working on a package with the following structure.

```
Package
  |- __init__.py
  |- dir
    |- subdir
      |- moduleB.py
      |- __init__.py 
    |- __init__.py
    |- moduleA.py
main.py
```

main.py tries to import moduleA, which in turn imports moduleB. However, it runs in to an error when it tries to import moduleA, citing an error at a line of code that has since been changed.

I figured this would is a caching issue, so I deleted all of the pycache files in the package but it still fails.

What can I do to fix this, and what can I do to ensure that this does not remain a problem?

[image: Click here for the error]

The actual code is

```
import tensorflow as tf
from UROP.data_structure.default_dictionary import DefaultDictionary


def default_distribution(shape, variation, name=''):
    return tf.truncated_normal(
        shape=shape,
        stddev=variation,
        name=name
    )
```

Comment: Could you include the error?

Comment: You get the error when `main.py` tries to `import Package.moduleA`? You may be getting different modules than you think. `os.path.realpath('Package.__file__`) would be interesting.

Comment: I will update with realpath as soon as possible tomorrow morning.

Comment: Also, step through the import with a debugger like pdb3. Maybe someone is doing something "clever" with paths.

Comment: When you get an error, it's always good to pay attention to what it's saying. In this case it says exactly what the problem is.

The module Research.data_structures.default_dictionary isn't being found. It could be a missing dependency or a problem with your lib path.

Comment: Thanks MrJLP, but that shouldn't be a problem, as the code has since been changed, so it doesn't rely on 'Research' any more.

Answer (score 0):

@tdelaney was correct, and stepping through with a debugger revealed that the kernel I was using redirected me to its own private cache. I was using Hydrogen in Atom, and restarting the computer cleared the cache and solved the problem.

However, I was unable to find a long-term solution to the cached dependencies that would not require re-starting my computer.